# Close form for sum on infinite radii

Tags: geometry, summation, closed-form, curves

$ABC $ is an isosceles right triangle, whose small sides are $1$. I want to find a close form for the sum of the infinite radii of the small circumferences created by the cevians. The numerical value of this sum is $ 0.39709... $

Furthermore what kind of curve pass by the centers of the circles?

[image]

Comment: This question reminds me of this [recent one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4710716/305862) even if it is different...

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4622423/398708) is a similar arrangement of circles, which has nice answers to the kinds of questions you are asking. If you draw tangent lines to the circles at the points where the circles touch each other, the tangent lines all meet at the same point $(2,2)$, so these tangent lines are cevians from a vertex of a triangle. The [sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/8337/398708) of the radii (excluding the biggest circle, which is outside the triangle) is $\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1$. The centres of the circles lie on $y=\frac14(x-2)^2$.

Comment: @Dan that's a nice discovery! But I guess that the answer is wrong because the circles radii are not decreasing like 1/n^2, the actual formula is given by the answer of Intelligenti pauca. By the way did you found a closed form for odd p?

Comment: @user967210 I don't mean that the link in my previous comment answers your question here; I'm just saying that the link shows another arrangement of circles that has nice values. I didn't find a closed form for odd $p$.

Answer (score 5):

Using the [formula for the inradius of a triangle](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Inradius.html) it is easy to compute the $n$-th radius:
$$
r_n={1\over 1+n\sqrt{n^2+2n+2}+(n+1)\sqrt{n^2+1}}.
$$
The sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty r_n$ is finite but Mathematica doesn't give a closed form for it, hence I doubt a nice formula can be found.